# GeoServer - prioritize labels with certain attribute value

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have a point layer that I serve as WMS with GeoServer. The points have language and name properties and some points have the same geometry so they overlap. What I want to do is to prioritize rendering of labels for certain language using SLD stylesheet.

Example: There are two points with same geometry, one has language value 5, the other has language value 7. I want only the name of point with language value 7 to be rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Priority` option](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html#priority-labeling) in your `TextSymbolizer` to favour one label over the others. The higher the value the more likely a label is to be used.

```
<Priority>
  <ogc:PropertyName>population</ogc:PropertyName>
</Priority>
```

Comment: From what I get, this will make a label with higher population value (in your case) a priority. But what if the value that I want to prioritize is not the highest one?

Comment: you can use some maths or an if_then function to make it the largest